# Adobe reader issue

Tags: adobe, acrobat

I downloaded a report (Customer report in PDF format) and when I tried to open report in Acrobat Reader DC, I  keep getting errr 
"An error exists on the page. Acrobat may not display the page currently. Please contact the person who create the PDF document to correct the problem".

I couldn't find answer for this question. I am using 17.012.20098.44270 version

Please help.

However I am able to open in Microsoft Edge

Comment: Acrobat Reader is quite a bit more strict than Edge. Also, Edge doesn't support the full specification so I'm guessing that it's just ignoring the broken parts of the PDF. If you can post the PDF somewhere I can tell you for sure.

Comment: @joelgeraci I cannot share my pdf file as it is my company's policy. Could you please help me with it based on error.

Comment: Without access to the document, there is no chance to help about the error. The best thing you can do is what the message says, and maybe advise that person to get informed about how to properly create a PDF. Although there is a slight chance that the file got messed up in transit.

Comment: If it is a simple PDF you may try to correct it by printing it to a pdf printer

Comment: If an Adobe viewer claims that the file is corrupt and can't be displayed, the likelihood of a viewer that *will* open the file *can* display it *correctly* is very low. Printing from Edge to PDF will not *correct* the problem it will simply burn the problem into a new, readable PDF.

Comment: Actually issue here is corrupt PDF file. Thanks all